# Javascript array of multiple object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert the 1 object with multiple item inside to an array of object? please see the picture below to understand what i meant, thanks

```
    var author = (`SELECT author, title, remarks, status, date FROM Transaction`, 1000, data=>{
      let obj = {[author: [], book: [], condition: [], status: [], date: []]}
        for(let x = 0; x < data.length; x++){
          obj.author.push(data[x][0]);
          obj.book.push(data[x][1]);
          obj.condition.push(data[x][2]);
          obj.status.push(data[x][3]);
          obj.date.push(data[x][4]);
        }
      console.log("obj: ", obj)
        return resolve(obj);
    })
```

The Current result of console.log("obj: ", obj)

```
{
    "authors": "testuser,testname",
    "books": "440936785,440936694",
    "conditions": "Very Good,New,",
    "status": "Not Available,Available",
    "datepublished": "Mon Mar 28 2022 18:42:24 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time),Mon Mar 28 2022 18:42:39 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)"
}
```

What I want result:

```
{
    "authors": "testname",
    "books": "440936694",
    "conditions": "New",
    "status": "Available",
    "datepublished": "Mon Mar 28 2022 18:42:24 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)"
},
{
    "authors": "testname",
    "books": "440936694",
    "conditions": "New,",
    "status": "Available",
    "datepublished": "Mon Mar 28 2022 18:42:39 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)"
}
```

Comment: No pictures of text please. Type this information and format it accordingly.

Comment: Also it would be helpful to paste the content of the `data` array

Comment: Impossible that your script produces that output. It has syntax errors in the line `let obj =`.

Comment: I updated my question, i remove the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of rows and want to create a list of objects. That means you have to convert every row to an object. Such a transformation is typically done with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which applies a function to every element in an array a produces a new array from the return value of that function:

```
const objects = data.map(row => ({
  author: row[0],
  book: row[1],
  condition: row[2],
  status: row[3],
  date: row[4],
}));
```

The library you are using to query the database might also be able to already create an object per row (using the column names) so you don't have to do the mapping yourself.

Comment: hello, Im sorry but i dont understand what youve meant

Comment: What exactly is unclear?